# Convert even numbers within a list to 1 and odds to 0. Bug with commas

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tree, nested-lists

So as the title explains it, I'm able to convert each even and odd number to their corresponding values, but with the data input I've got a comma. Which creates extra `L[]`. Let me show you an expected result with mine.

Expected result> `binariza (L [E 1,L [E 2,E 3],E 4]) => L [E 0,L [E 1,E 0],E 1]`

My result> `binariza (L [E 1,L [E 2,E 3],E 4]) => L [E 0,L [L [E 1,L [E 0,L []]],L [E 1,L []]]]`

Here's my code, could someone explain me how to avoid encapsulating all in `L[]` every time a comma is found.

```
data LA e = L [LA e] | E e deriving Show

binariza :: LA Integer -> LA Integer 
binariza (L[]) =  L[]
binariza (E num) =
     if (even num) then
        E 1
        else
            E 0
 binariza (L (x:resto)) =
     L [(binariza x), (binariza (L resto))]
```

Note: My solution must be recursive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, `[a,b,c,d]` is shorthand for `a:b:c:d:[]`....  So the extra `[]` is coming from the extra empty array.

What you really want is to map `binariza` onto each element within the array, which you can do using `map`.

Since "my solution must be recursive" = "this is homework", I won't show you the actual line, but you should be able to easily rewrite the last case in your function above to use `map` and get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @jamshidh ! I was only looking for an advise or explanation. Although I've got a question, using map wouldn't make it recursive as I believe right? "map (validate if even or odd then replace value to 0 or 1) L[...]". How then could it be recursive, if you could guide me please

Comment: Since binariza calls binariza, it is recursive....  The main point is that binariza gets applied all the way down the tree.  If you just change the last case above, the recursion will still be very explicit.

Comment: I keep getting this error: "Couldn't match expected type ‘LA Integer’
with actual type ‘[LA Integer]’" . At first I was respecting the "map function list", but then depending on where I put map I would end up with this error too "Couldn't match expected type ‘[LA Integer]’ with actual type ‘LA Integer’" could you please explain me why

Comment: Those errors mean that you are using a list where you need an item or the vice-versa....  I don't know for sure without seeing the code, but remember that if you want to pull out the full list from the pattern matching, use `f (L theList)`, and if you use `f (L (item:rest))`, then `item` is a simple item.